# Why is Grafana dashboard showing no data

Tags: prometheus, grafana

[grafana setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GKDz.png)
Can anyone look at this setup and tell me whats wrong why is dashboard not seeing any data ? why the query returning empty array of data ?

Following are the grafana query inspector section logs:

```
Object
request:Object
url:"http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=sum(http_requests_total%7Bmethod%3D%22GET%22%7D%20offset%205m)&time=1622177340&timeout=60s"
method:"GET"
hideFromInspector:false
response:Object
status:"success"
data:Object
resultType:"vector"
result:Array[0]
```

Comment: Which exporter generate the "http_requests_total" metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether Prometheus is up and running or not. If prometheus is up please check PromQL response for your data in your prometheus. Looks like communication between your prometheus and app service is broken.